# Difference between Tree Sort and Quick Sort?

Tags: sorting, tree, binary-search-tree, quicksort, treesort

The TreeSort uses Binary Search Trees for sorting the elements in the array, while the QuickSort uses a concept of "pivot" which sounds almost exactly as the concept of binary search trees. Apart from the basic fact that TreeSort uses an actual tree while QuickSort does not, what is the main difference?

Comment: There is so much different,  Binary Search Trees is a sorted data structure, `QuickSort` is algorithm to sort a list, You can imagine BST or other kind of sorted tree structure  as a `Collection`  with basic operation like: Insert, Find, Delete, Update much like `HashMap` but the data is sorted,

Comment: Thank you, but I know that part. I wanted to know whether there is any difference between the internal workings and the time complexity related to the sorting of the list only.

Comment: Quicksort has Average `O(n\log n)`, And Worst-case of `O(n^2)`,In Other Hand, BST has Average `O(log n)`, Worst-case of `O(n)` base on insertion, internal workings is very different  also, where Quicksort divide item into subproblem and sort recursively,  This is why its has time complexity  of `O(n\log n)`, In other hand BST don't check any unnecessary checkup, binary mean 2, So its has 2 child, every insertion is sorted in place, thats why it explain `O(log n)`

Comment: This question seems too broad to me: there are just too many aspects that can be considered here. Like: quick sort is in-place, and *swaps* values. Neither is true for tree sort. There is the analysis of time and space complexity, which input orders lead to worst/best cases, which actual *variants* of these algorithms have to be considered (think: choice/calculation of pivot), ...etc, ...etc.